# Jest Testing in Vue

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

How would use Jest Test to test this method:

```
  delayedFetch() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.fetchData();
  }, 1000);
```

I have tried using Async and await but I'm prob using it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to test code with side effects, and you did not provide the entire context, but I try to help.

I think the `this` in the `this.fetchData()` inside the `setTimeout` is referencing the `delayedFetch` method itself. (I don't know it is your intention, as far as How I use vue.js

But anyway you can find, how to test setTimeouts here [link to jest doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html)

Here is a simple implementation

```js
const someObj = {
  // I assume the delayedFetch is some method of an object
  fetchData() {
    return "some-data";
  },
  delayedFetch() {
    const vue = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      vue.fetchData();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

jest.useFakeTimers();

test("delayedFetchTest", () => {
  someObj.delayedFetch();

  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 1000);
})
```